# Can I play a game on a second device with the same profile with out starting over?

Tags: google-play-store

I have been playing boom beach on an android tablet. The tablet is no longer accessible to me. Can I play the game on another android tablet without starting over?

Answer (score 1):

If you signed into you Google+ account while playing the game, then progress is synchronised across to the second device.

While playing the game, sign into your Google+ account on the second device. This will give you the option to load your existing progress.

If you didn't sign into to your Google+ account on the first device, then I'm afraid it isn't possible without access to the device.

Comment: When playing on the first device the Google play drop down  with the game controller drops down from the top with my name. Does that mean I have signed in?

Comment: Yes that's right. You can also check if you are signed in by going to "Settings" in the app. There should be a box that says "Google+ sign-in" which will say "Connected" if you are connected.